# ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'isSelected' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I just want to update a property value of an array element in My NgRx Store Object after cloning it to avoid mutation but no success.
Here is the Reducer Code:

```
on(
    myActions.elementDeselected,
    (state, { desiredId}) => {
    const childArrayCopy=[...state.selectedObject.childArray.slice(0)];
    const childArray = childArrayCopy.map(arrayElement=> {
        if (arrayElement.id === desiredId) {
          arrayElement.isSelected = false;
          return arrayElement;
        }
        return arrayElement;
      });

      return {
        ...state,
        selectedObject: {
          ...state.selectedObject,
          ...childArray
        }
      };
    }
  ),
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `arrayElement` is read-only, you have to copy *it*, too:

```
const childArray = childArrayCopy.map(arrayElement=> {
  if (arrayElement.id === desiredId) {
    arrayElement = {...arrayElement, isSelected: false}; // <===
  }
  return arrayElement;
});
```

That uses the object property version of spread to create a new object with a copy of the old object's properties, then updating `isSelected` to be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Mutation of store objects are not allowed, you should always create a copy, also for nested objects:

```
const childArray = childArrayCopy.map(arrayElement=> ({
  ...arrayElement,
  isSelected: arrayElement.id === desiredId ? false : arrayElement.isSelected
}));
```

Comment: Is it necessary to create a copy even when not updating it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it definitely is not, but I like compact code, it's immediately visible that the `isSelected` property is targeted, and in light of some extra similar ifs in the same loop, it would only need one extra line as opposed to 3. But it's just personal preference. Although when this is used on an array of +1000 elements and it's ran frequently, it might be advisable to optimize it indeed

Comment: Okay, thanks. I wasn't sure if there was a Redux subtlety here I didn't know. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Also, on the odd chance that the async pipe is not used, and the angular component is using the `arrayElement` as an input on the object, and the component uses `OnPush`, it could be that the component is not updated, because the reference of the object did not change :). I believe when somebody is using the `.subscribe` in their component code, this could happen as well. So mainly, when using relatively bad practice code, you might run into issues